# Polymer 1.0 two-way binding with textarea

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I have this simple two-way data binding with textarea:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <style>
  </style>

  <template>
    <button on-click="click">Click me!</button>
    <textarea>{{element}}</textarea>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "my-element",

    properties: {
      element: {
        type: String,
        value: "Default value",
        notify: true
      }
    },

    click: function() {
      console.log(this.element);
    }
  });
</script>
```

The textarea show up with "Default Value". When I change this value and then click on the button, the console still log out `Default value` instead of the text that I just typed in. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymer.js two-way binding to textarea value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595316/polymer-js-two-way-binding-to-textarea-value)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<iron-autogrow-textarea>` to allow data binding.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <style>
  </style>

  <template>
    <button on-click="click">Click me!</button>
    <iron-autogrow-textarea bind-value="{{element}}"></iron-autogrow-textarea>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "my-element",

    properties: {
      element: {
        type: String,
        value: "Default value",
      }
    },

    click: function() {
      console.log(this.element);
    }
  });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Documentation is [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-autogrow-textarea).