# iron-request doesn't make more than one request

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am working with the [Polymer 2](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview) library.  Whenever I try to make multiple requests using [iron-request](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-request), the code only ever seems to make a POST request on the first initiation.  Any subsequent requests seem to be ignored, even when data that is set to be sent to the server is different from the initial request.

I've written a small example in this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/cozVKUdQ2q2SV46rcCTL?p=preview

I created a iron-request and a button element to initiate the request like so:

```
<paper-button on-click="save" class="green">Send</paper-button>
...
<iron-request id="xhr"></iron-request>
```

The save function is setup to take text from a textarea and send that off to a server.

```
save() {
    var response = this.$.xhr.send({
      url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: {
        content: this.inputdata
      },
      method: "POST"
    });
    var poly = this;
    this.$.xhr.completes.then(function(data) {
      console.log("finished");
      poly.$.responsetext.innerHTML = data.response;
    })
```

The code in question is in the "element1.html" file.  If you try sending different text payloads, only the first request will be send.  (You can see in the response box that the form "content" field stays the same.)

Any idea what is going on?  I'm thinking that I would have to create new iron-request elements everytime I need to make a new request... but that doesn't sound like a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, `iron-request` has been built to send a single HTTP request. I had a quick look at the its implementation. The `send` method will actually just return `null` and not do anything, if the request has a status that is larger 0 than, which will be the case if you have used it before.

While you could create a new `iron-request` element for each request, it is not elegant (as you said yourself). Instead, you could work with `iron-ajax`. You can find some instructions on its [documentation page](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/elements/iron-ajax).

Your `<iron-request>` can be rewritten as this.

```
<iron-ajax id="xhr" url="https://httpbin.org/post" content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST" body="[[inputdata]]" on-response="onXhrSuccess"></iron-ajax>
```

Your save function,

```
save() {
    this.$.xhr.generateRequest();
}

onXhrSuccess(event, request) {
    console.log("finished");
    poly.$.responsetext.innerHTML = event.detail.response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `<iron-ajax>` seems to be making multiple requests... But I'm having a bit of trouble implementing these changes in the plunker link I provided. Would one of you be able to provide a fully working example? Here is what I have so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/nCZg3wch99WOtr8OdbLY?p=preview
The text field doesn't seem to update the data being sent. Maybe a data binding issue?

Comment: @chaseme That is caused by a different problem with data-binding to textareas. You can find a solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597039/594056).  And here's the updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LBpi15g3z1Q4hKyfcGQQ?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect. That works. I did see that solution regarding the textarea previously, however I didn't know that also applied to Polymer 2.x as well.